# change attributes of SVG object before appending it to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, design-patterns, svg

Context:

I'm working on an app where I add elements dynamically to a container via `myModule.getElement()` . That will return me a template:

```
function getElement(){

    var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    return template;
}
```

and then I'll just append it to a container.
The template contains an SVG object.

I'd like though to 'initialize' the element, before appending it to the DOM (or right after  doing so), for example:

```
$(template).find("path, polygon, circle").attr("fill", "#ddd");
```

But that doesn't work, and my guess is because at that point the element hasn't been added to the DOM (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I can do this:

```
for (var i = numElements; i > 0; i--) {
    elArray.push(myModule.getElement());
    container.append(elArray[i]);
};
myModule.initializeElements();
```

and then in MyModule::

```
function initElements(){
    $('.elClass').find("path, polygon, circle").attr("fill", "#ddd");
}
```

But it doesn't feel good. I wonder if I could change the properties of the SVG object before  it's been appended to the DOM, is that possible?

I read that I could extend the append function and create a trigger for an event handler to it, but that seems overly complex to this situation.

Any ideas? I'm also not tied to this pattern/architecture, this is a very simple case and I could easily re-arrange it.

Comment: *"But that won't work because the element hasn't been added to the DOM (please correct me if I'm wrong)."* Should work, did you try it?

Comment: yes I sure did! it doesn't

Comment: Works for me (sans Handlebars): http://jsbin.com/foxomo/1

Comment: Hmm..i'm trying to dismiss Handlebars. But I don't wanna throw the whole SVG object inside my module, so I'll need to do an ajax request to load the html template(that's in the same server, and same directory as the module script)? I feel stupid to ask that and I'm mad at myself that I cannot see other simpler solutions to this problem other than that

Comment: I 've just found [this](http://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/)!! Got very excited, but too bad it doesn't seem to work, can find the paths with `$(el).find()` but the attributes don't change, as it did when using  the Handlebars template (considering the elements were appended to DOM)